# How to enable memory monitoring in Xdebug?

Tags: php, drupal-7, xdebug, php-7.1

I am trying to use Xdebug for my Drupal project debugging. In some documentations, I saw that the Xdebug is able to find memory leaks as well. I tried to use that facility. But I am not getting any logs regarding that.

I configured my 20-xdebug.ini as follows

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1 
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/home/myname/Desktop/xdebug/"
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/home/myname/Desktop/xdebug/"
xdebug.remote_log="/home/myname/Desktop/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.collect_params=1
xdebug.trace_format=1
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

I am able to connect NetBeans with Xdebug and I can go through each break points. But there are no logs regarding this in the `/tmp` folder and there are no log files in the above given paths as well.

**Am I doing something wrong? Please assist me on this.**

Comment: If no logs is generated .. then check access permissions & actual path correctness. Log will be created by the user that is used to run your web server (Apache/nginx/etc) unless you do this in CLI mode. Xdebug will generate log file (`xdebug.remote_log`) if such path is specified .. as i's used for checking what's going on/why debug does not work etc.

Comment: NOTE: debugging (stepping through the code) and profiling are a bit different things and it does not make sense to have both of them at the same time (debugging means "slowly stepping though each line" while profiling "see how much time it takes to execute this block") so you better either debug or profile and not two at once.

Comment: @LazyOne, Thanks for the suggestions. It is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you need
xdebug.show_mem_delta = 1

> xdebug.show_mem_delta
>
> Type: integer, Default value: 0
>
> When this setting is set to something != 0 Xdebug's human-readable
>   generated trace files will show the difference in memory usage between
>   function calls. If Xdebug is configured to generate computer-readable
>   trace files then they will always show this information.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Will try this. But as I mentioned in the question, I am not getting any log details. Let me check this.